# Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE INDEX

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working with rails 2.3.5 application, in witch I have this field

```
t.string   "trip_cities",             :limit => 256
```

And this index

```
add_index "bookings", ["trip_cities"], :name => "trip_cities"
```

When I try to execute:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:load
```

I receive this error `Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: CREATE  INDEX 'trip_cities' ON 'bookings' ('trip_cities')` and don't quite know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like the default collation uses the UTF8 character set.

MySQL limits the length of keys by bytes, not characters.  Since the UTF8 implementation MySQL uses allows for 3 bytes per character, the max length of a key on a UTF8 column is 3 times the key length in characters (the key length is the full length of the field if not explicitly specified).

In this case the max key length would be `256 * 3` which is `768`.  You need to either limit the length of the key or change the collation of the column.

Comment: This is actually a working "update" : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9855#issuecomment-28874587

Answer (score 9):

how about changing the migration itself:

```
remove_index "bookings", :name => :trip_cities
add_index "bookings", ["trip_cities"], :name => :trip_cities, :length => { :trip_cities => 255 }
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer -- I assume this is what the accepted answer means by "change the collation of the column", but this actually shows how to do it.

Comment: @DavidMoles This doesn't change the collation, it just limits the data so it fits within the constraints imposed by the existing collation.  Changing the collation would need to happen in the definition of the table on the server.  However, this may still be a better way to get past this issue if the structure cannot be changed.

Comment: @G-Nugget Aha. Do you think you could update your answer with an example of how you change the collation?

Answer (score 5):

You should recreate your database with correct options.

[This](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/1244#issuecomment-314412303) helped to me with same problem

```
CREATE DATABASE ${DB} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Helped me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set a limit on the length of the string to 191 characters, example:

```
t.string :project, index: { unique: true }, limit: 191
```

OR

Use this patch: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9855#issuecomment-390366184

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `length` option to the index in `schema.rb` worked for me:

```
t.index ["your_index", "fields"], name: "index_your_index_fields", unique: true, length: 191
```

I'd noticed when migrating Rails was doing this automatically, thought this wasn't committed to the repo. I had to run `rails schema:load` on another machine and it wasn't working, though adding the above solved this.

Hope that helps someone.